# Confused about images, reverse images.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am confused over a seemingly simple practice question which I will post below. I am confused over the concept as well, but this question just helps to show what it is I am not understanding.

> $$\text{Let }f(x)=\frac 1 {x^2}, x \neq 0, x\in \mathbb R$$

a) Determine the direct image $f(E)$ where $E=\{x \in \mathbb R :1 \le x \le 2\}$

So for part a, I assume by image it just means what values of y will appear if we map E under f? i.e., the set y greater than 1/4 and less then 1? So I would think the answer would be $\{y\in \mathbb R: \frac 1 4 \le y \le 1\}$. But the correct answer given is $f(E)=\{x\in \mathbb R: \frac 1 4 \le x \le 1\}$

b) Determine the inverse image $f^{-1}(G)$ where $G=\{x\in \mathbb R:1\le x \le 4\}$

So what exactly is this asking to find? I would have thought it would have been $f^{-1}(G)=\{1\le x\le  \frac 1 2\}$ but the answer given is "*The singleton* $\{1\}$".

I hope what I am asking is clear. Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: This can be easily solved if you just write down the definitions of direct and reverse image of a set. I can't think of any answer which is not writing down the definitions, and/or solving this particular problem/similar example for you. So instead, I am not going to write an answer. **You** are going to open your book and read the definitions, and solve this yourself.

Comment: For a), whether the generic element of a set is named $x$ or $y$ or FredFlintstone is immaterial. Your answer is exactly the given one there.

Comment: For $\{ x \in \mathbb R : 1/4 ≤ x ≤ 1 \}$ the variable $x$ is to be read as "bound"; thus $\{ x \in \mathbb R : 1/4 ≤ x ≤ 1 \}$ and $\{ y \in \mathbb R : 1/4 ≤ y ≤ 1 \}$ define the "same" set.

Comment: Okay ofcourse I have tried that @AsafKaragila, and I understand the  part a. But even with the definition open I don't see how the answer to B is "the singleton {1}". Could you at least conform to me that this is correct? or a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second question seems a bit weird to me... if what you mean by inverse image of f is preimage, then it should be {$x\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{1}{2}\le|x|\le 1$}
But I might be wrong

Comment: thanks for the comment, yes part B is the part I am more confused about.